# how to select dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request#

If you go to this page, i have used following codes in order to give 'fadein' effects as i scroll through page.
I have done that by using jquery addclass and animate.css

(https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

and at the same time i used jscroll.js to give it infinite scrolling effect as well.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('tr').waypoint(function() {
        jQuery('tr').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    }, {
        offset: '75%'
    });});
```

and here is the script that i use for infinite scrolling

```
/* infinite scroll */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.board_content').jscroll({
        loadingHtml: '<center><img src="layouts/window/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...</center>',
        padding: 0,
        contentSelector: '.board_list',
        autoTriggerUntil: 5,
        nextSelector:'.next_button'
    }); 
});
```

As you can see, the first 10  are visible because the addclass worked fine.

but for the next 20 s remain opacity:0 because they are dynamically added to the dom later on by jscroll.js

could anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

thanks.

Comment: you need to use jQuery on() function when binding the events. If not, only existing elements in the DOM will be bound. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: so i've heard. but in this case i would have to on.click on something wouldn't I? is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: what is your trigger then? scrolling? you can bind it on the scroll event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the `waypoint` script after the content added to bind them too.

Something like:

```
$('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...',
    padding: 20,
    nextSelector: 'a.jscroll-next:last',
    contentSelector: 'li',
    callback: function() {
       jQuery('tr').waypoint(function() {
          jQuery('tr').addClass('animated fadeIn');
          }, {
             offset: '75%'
       });
    }
});
```